# How to create update package from maven dependency that has only changes from last build

Tags: java, git, maven

I want to create an update package for a product. The update package should only contain the libraries are has changes since last build. How to get the library changes from maven?

Previously, before using maven we used commit all the library jars in the git repository. So, it was pretty much straight forward approach to get differences from git.

Comment: Maven is rather a build tool. I didn't get what made your life difficult commiting to a similar git repo structure when started using maven.

Comment: Should I create a separate git repo and commit dependent jars into it to get difference? What do you suggest ? @vahdet

Comment: @palash Don't put jars into git.

Comment: Then, what will be the solution to find out the new jars? @JFMeier

Answer (score 2):

I do not know an out of the box solution. What you could do:

- Run `mvn dependency:list` with every build and save the result (in a database etc.).
- Write a script that reads both lists and extracts the differences.
- Use the maven dependency plugin to download the extracted differences.